# How to create nice looking CSV with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, csv

I'm using **codeigniter** to develop a system.
My issue here is kinda easy for you I believe.
This is my codeignter code.

```
$delimiter = ",";
$newline = "\r\n";
$data= $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($MYSQLRESULT,$delimiter, $newline);
write_file('./public/uploads/client.csv', $data);
```

But when it creates the csv file, it looks like this

[image: http://imgur.com/Azj52oZ]

Is there a way to make it look nice? I want headers stay seperated and all fields as well. I dont want commas or anything.
Help please. I think problem is about my delimiters but I don't know what to do.

EDIT: I want it to look like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/uGhTdPV]

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of 'nice' output?

Comment: You cant just get rid of the quotes without breaking your CSV file. The quotes are there to indicate where a value starts and ends and any quotes within a value are escaped so they won't be confused with the outer quotes. You can rewrite the CSV so that instead of quotes it uses nothing and then set your delimiter as a tab/space, but then you would need to escape any tabs/spaces within a value. Also, whatever application you are using to view it would need to be told what the new delimiter is. It's really not worth it. Keep it as it and any smart spreadsheet program should be able to parse it.

Comment: So I can not place each value in a box by any means?

Comment: Apparently the program you are using is not correctly parsing the file to display. For instance if I open a CSV file like yours in my office program it will parse and display the file as you intend (nice).

Comment: The CSV is formatted correctly, the problem is the application you are using to open the csv. Usually when opening a csv in say open office, you will be prompted with a screen to input which characters you are using for delimiters, and whether the data is wrapped in double quotations or not.

Answer (score 0):

tell excel the separator character with sep=, on the first line

```
write_file('./public/uploads/client.csv', "sep=,\n" . $data);
```